# Type Mismatch when using System.in.read()

Tags: java, types, mismatch

I am trying to write a program in Java that counts the number of occurrences of each letter in a string of text, and print out a histogram tallying how many of each letter are present. I have most of the code, but get an error when I try to use `System.in.read()`. The code that is bothering me is this:

```
 static String sentence = new String();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    sentence = System.in.read();
```

when I compile, I get:

```
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to java.lang.String
```

Where is this int coming from, when I clearly defined `sentence` as a string, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sentence` is a `String`, but if you read the javadocs for `System.in` you'll see it's an `InputStream`, and `InputStream.read()` returns an `int` (the character code of the first character read, or `-1` if the `read()` hits end-of-file). The type of the righthand side of the assignment has to be assignable to the type of the lefthand side of the assignment, either by being the same class or primitive type, a subclass, implementing the interface if the lhs is an interface, or casting.

If you want to read more than a character at a time, look at some of the other `io` classes. `java.util.Scanner` might also be useful in this case.

Comment: +1. Clarification: `System.in.read()` gives you the numerical representation of which character (not string) was given by the user. For all intents and purposes, this means that it only gives you the first character pressed (represented as the identification number of said character), not a variable length string entered by the user.